# Tuple in list cannot be changed directly?

Tags: python, list, tuples

There's a programming problem for an online course which requires me to **modify an item in a list of tuples**. Strange, I know. Looking at some other questions on Stack Overflow, commenters have noted that a dictionary would make more sense.

However, data structures aside, the following code does not work:

```
l = [(0, 'apples'), (1, 'pears'), (2, 'bananas')]

for item in l:
    if item[0] == 1:
        item = 'something else'
```

Nope. It stays exactly the same. But when I write the loop differently, as:

```
for index in range(len(l)-1):
    if l[index][0] == 1:
        l[index] = 'what is this'
```

the middle item in the list is successfully changed, even though it is a tuple. I don't like the second piece of code; it seems unnecessarily verbose. Shouldn't it work either way? I'm considering reporting this behavior as a bug in Python (tried both 2.7 and 3.4).

Comment: tuples are immutable

Comment: @PadraicCunningham i think he wants to replace the item in the list (poorly named I know)

Comment: @JoranBeasley, you are probably right, I just went by the title ;)

Comment: If you were changing using a loop, you should use enumerate. Only in your second example are you actually accessing an index in the list. The first just creates a variable item equal to `'something else'`

Answer (score 3):

```
items = [(0, 'apples'), (1, 'pears'), (2, 'bananas')]
print [item if item[0] != 1 else "something else" for item in items]
```

is normally how you would do this in python

Answer (score 3):

If you want to change inplace use enumerate not range:

```
l = [(0, 'apples'), (1, 'pears'), (2, 'bananas')]

for ind, tup in enumerate(l):
    if tup[0] == 1:
        l[ind] = "something else"
print(l)
```

Or you can use `l[:]` with a list comprehension to change the original list:

```
l[:] = ["something else" if tup[0] == 1 else tup for  tup in l]

print(l)
```

Or use a generator expression:

```
l[:] = ("something else" if tup[0] == 1 else tup for  tup in l)

print(l)
```

`item = 'something else'` simply creates a variable `item`, actually indexing the list `l[ind]` and assigning a new value with `=` changes the item in the list.

As far as the *the middle item in the list is successfully changed, even though it is a tuple* goes, yes that is expected behaviour, you are changing an element in the list not an element in the tuple. If you try indexing the tuple and updating a value in that then it would be a different story, a `TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment` because tuples are immutable.

Comment: `l[:] with a list comprehension to change the original list` ... sort of :P (+1 anyway)

Comment: @JoranBeasley, `id` before and after will remain the same so good enough for me ;)

Comment: I know you know the nuance :P ... I was just subtly pointing out a little hand wavy magic

Comment: @JoranBeasley, what can I say I grew up watching Paul Daniels ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is not a bug.

In the first example you are assigning a local variable name with `item = 'something else'`. Ie. `item` no longer refers to a tuple in the list. It is a new variable.

In the second example you are replacing elements in a list (which is mutable).

See Joran's answer for how you should do this.

Comment: great answer ... It is probably worth noting in the first example that it creates a local variable item that is then overwritten, this does not change the original item in the list (as implied but may want to really spell it out)

Comment: @JoranBeasley Clarified :)